# Minimum sum in a 2D matrix choosing contiguous sub arrays from each row

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm

Given is a data set of number of passengers and taxi driver's time taken to cater each passenger, output the minimum time required by the taxi agency to transfer all passengers.

Constraints:

1. A driver would like to cater to the next consecutive passenger number. (i.e D1 would go with P1, P2 rather than P1, P3. because his contiguous passenger number chain is broken).
2. A driver once chosen for the task will not be allowed to participate again. (i.e if D1 goes with P1,P2 and D3 goes with P3, D1 is not considered back for P4, D3 can be considered, as P4 will be contiguous with P3).

Input is a m*n matrix, output the minimum time.

Example:

```
    P1 P2 P3 P4
D1  2  2  1  2
D2  3  1  2  1
D3  4  2  3  1
```

Output(minimum time) : 6

**Explanation** :

we can choose D1 for P1,P2,P3 and D3 for P4 (2+2+1+1 = 6)

or we can choose D1 for P1,P2,P3 and D2 for P4 (2+2+1+1 = 6)

or we can choose D1 for P1, D2 for P2,P3 and D3 for P4 (2+1+2+1 = 6)

or we can choose D1 for P1 and D2 for P2,P3,P4 (2+1+2+1 = 6)

or we can choose D2 for P1,P2, D1 for P3, and D3 for P4 (3+1+1+1 = 6)

PS: It's a modified [Assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), but unable to crack the solution.

Comment: People have been posting this question with different descriptions over and over during the past few days. Techgig codegladiators semi final round1 techgig.com/codegladiators . The problem is active till july 6th for submissions. (An accepted solution is actually posted on SO, but not under the algorithm tag.)

Comment: Yea, I should have probably posted this after 6th of July. I was just curious to know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, The only diffrence from a classical assignement problem is that in case of equality, you should maximize `∑Pi==Di`.

This can be done by reducing the cost of `Mat[i][i]` by an infinitesimal number. In practice 1/1024 is enough if `n<<1024`.

Once you have done this, you can solve your problem using standard algorithms such as the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).